# controller in app.js isn't working for ionic project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic project, in app.js, I wrote some code but it doesn't work when I use the controller in index.html file.

How do I make it work?

app.js:

```
var app= angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope)
     {
        $scope.notes =
      [
          {
               title:'First note'
               description:'This is my first note'
          },
          {
               title:'Second Note'
               description:'second note'
          }
      ]; 
});
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">InfoNote</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ListCtrl">
          <div class ="list">
             <div class ="item" ng-repeat="note in notes" >
                  {{note.title}}
              </div>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is not working

Comment: What state did you define for index.html ?

Comment: @Habkamas i didn't understand quite but i didn't use any state i guess i just wrote a controller code in app.js (the code you are seeing) and tried to use it on the index.html file of ionic blank template..for better understanding the use of that particular code..but it didn't work ...I went through the docs of ionic framework site but still not working... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot **comma** in your `JSON`. In your `controller`, try again with this :

```
app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope)

 {
    $scope.notes =
  [

      {
           title:'First note',
           description:'This is my first note'
      },
      {
           title:'Second Note',
           description:'second note'

      }
  ]; 
});
```

Comment: thank you very very very much.....I can't vote  your answer right now cause my reputation is under 15 .Once I get reputation i will vote your answer.... :D

Comment: @MD.SazidHasanDip you can't UPVOTE his answer, but you still can ACCEPT it ;) Clic on the green arrow